# Websphere ejb build

Tags: websphere-8

I am trying to run ejbdeploy.sh on my Linux server which has websphere 8.5.5.9 and my project which I want to build is in java 8 whenever I run ejbdeploy.sh on server it gives me compilation errors for my code which is in java 7 or 8 and the compilation error says that resource level bellow 1.7
Clearly it is trying to compile my code using Java 6.
Please provide me with the approach to deal with this problem and build the project either in java 7 or java 8

Comment: My ejb stub which is created by ejbdeploy is always compiled with Java 6 even though on the IBM websphere site they say that default jdk change should make the build of ejb stub to 7 but this is not happening in my case so only viable alternative for me now is to not include code above java 6 in my ejb files or use websphere 9 package​ to build the ejb as on the website they say that ejbdeploy in case of websphere 9 has a default compiler set to java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new .sh file included in the websphere packaging. I specifically don't know from when but I replace ejbdeploy.sh with createEjbstubs.sh and the parameters for createEjbstubs.sh are different from that of ejbdeploy.sh but still they are similar so you can change your build commands to now use createEjbstubs instead of ejbdeploy and it works fine on websphere 8.5.5.9.